# log in size of output array for filter output vector in VHDL

Tags: filter, vhdl

I implement a filter with the following parameters:

```
taps = 20;
data_wigth = 10;
filter_wigth = 10;
interpolation_factor = 4;
```

I have found that

```
output: out std_logic_vector( ( M * data_width + filter_width+ log2(taps)- 1) downto 0)
```

Why is log2(taps)?

Answer (score 2):

You are summing the outputs of the taps, so to avoid overflow the word length grows as ceil (log2 of the number of taps).