# ceil(log2(x)) or ceil(log2(x)) - 1 [repeat the post question]

Tags: vhdl

I am sorry I am asking again. It was asked in this post  [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/561468/log-in-size-of-output-array-for-filter-output-vector-in-vhdl/561526#561526).

if N vectors are sum up, I need `ceil(log2(x))` or `ceil(log2(x))-1` additional bits?

PS I am not able to add comments to the post was linked. i don't have 50 points of reputation.

**Edit**

x is a number of elements which will be summed up

Comment: this site is Q&A ... it is not a forum ... you do not ask questions about your problem in someone else's comments ... please add all information to your post above ... do not link another question

Comment: Additional bits?  What does (x) represent? Your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes unsigned integers. It can probably be extended to other types also.
To find out the worst case, assume *all* the numbers added are maximum values that an \$n\$ bit number can hold; i.e, \$(2^n - 1)\$. Let's consider the case where we add \$x\$ such numbers. The result of adding \$x\$ such maximum values is

$$
\begin{align}
x\cdot(2^n - 1) &={} 2^{log_2 x}(2^n - 1) \\
&={} 2^{log_2 x}\cdot 2^n - 2^{log_2 x}\\
&={} 2^{n + log_2 x} - 2^{log_2 x}
\end{align}
$$

The term being subtracted will only reduce the size of the result. Lets ignore it. So the sum requires \$n+ log_2 x\$ bits to represent it; i.e. number of additional bits is \$log_2 x\$. Since it may not be an integer, round it **up** to \$\mathrm{ceil}( log_2 x)\$.

The linked question contains a `-1`. I think that it is becuase they use zero based indexing as in `downto 0`. So there are actually \$\mathrm{ceil}( log_2 x)\$ additional bits.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to focus on for the problem you are looking at is what type is the value stored in.  The reason you need to know what type it is stored in is because you need to know how many bytes are used.  That's how overflow occurs, the bytes cannot contain the value.

```
Math.log2(3) = 1.584962500721156 // float
Math.ceil(Math.log2(3)) = 2 // integer
Math.ceil(Math.log2(3)) - 1 = 1 // still an integer
```

Depending upon language, the float will take 8 bytes, while the integer will take 4 bytes.
It's difficult to tell what the original post or this post is really getting at, but I'm assuming that at some point of adding the float values overflows and you're attempting to get around this.

With the additional understanding of what the ceil() does it should help you determine how to get to your final solution.
ceil() pushes the value up to the next integer value and returns an integer (thus converting the float to an int).

**Maximum Values**

Also, since the Float type is stored in a larger number of bytes, its max value is larger than the integer (only 4 bytes) so that means since you are converting to a integer you need to understand that the new max value will only be up to the size of an integer.